# Issues with deploying Node.js app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to deploy a simple app I created by following an online tutorial to Heroku. The app deployed fine but when I open it I get the following message:

```
"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments."
```

In the logs I see the following:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=testapp.herokuapp.com request_id=245c73e7-1c11-4c98-8bb5-92dee6599ef2 fwd="64.46.7.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

All of the tutorials I have read online about deploying a Node.js app to Heroku say that I need to define a Procfile and add something like this:

```
web: node server.js
```

I don't have a server.js file in my app so what file would I specify here? Would it be the app.js that I have in the root directory or the www file that I have in my bin folder? I am really confused...

Once I update the Procfile do I need to restart heroku or redeploy my whole app for it to take effect?

Thanks for the help!

### EDIT:

A bit further above in the log I see the following:

```
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266570+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:33
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266584+00:00 app[web.1]:   var skinClassName = 'Skin' + NativeClass.name;
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266585+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266586+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266588+00:00 app[web.1]:     at makeSkinClass (/app/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:33:43)
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266587+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266589+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/grid.js:6:35)
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266589+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266590+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266591+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266591+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266592+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266592+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266594+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-04-05T01:19:48.266593+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/db.js:22:16)
```

Is this what is triggering the error with the app?

Comment: Try to use the same name for the file and the specification in Profile, if your entry point file is `app.js` set at Profile `web: node app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution to fix this module would be to add mongodb@1.4.4 as a dependency as the issue stems from the fact that mongoskin switched (accidentially) to a peer dependency for mongodb@2.X which it does not support.